# When I made The WebGl Link it showed this error WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices. Cube Runner

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, runtime-error, hosting, project

When I made The WebGl Link it showed this error
WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.
Cube Runner
You can check it out by going to this link below and clicking on Run Game
https://atharv-radhey.itch.io/cuberunner
Please Tell me Solution I have wasted 30hours for solving that error and now I am asking it here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately unitys WebGL is not supported for mobile devices. See here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html

For some highend mobile devices it could work however.

I can see the error `unityFramework is not defined`. As a solution you should try to build without compression.

Comment: Or configure the webserver to handle the new unity compression stuff